# sonarqube won't start with an elasticsearch error

Tags: java, elasticsearch, initialization, sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

Sonarqube 5.4 and java 8 here.

Tried this on both sonarqube 5.1 and with java 7 and I get the same results.

```
2016.03.29 10:49:23 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to execute ES put mapping request on indices 'rules' on type 'rule' with source '{"dynamic":false,"_id":{"path":"key"},"properties":{"debtRemFnOffset":{"index":"analyzed","index_analyzer":"keyword","search_analyzer":"whitespace","type":"string"},"_debtChar":{"index":"analyzed","index_analyzer":"keyword","search_analyzer":"whitespace","type":"string"},"_key":{"index":"analyzed","index_analyzer":"keyword","search_analyzer":"whitespace","type":"string"},"debtRemFnTypeOverloaded":{"type":"boolean"},"noteLogin":{"index":"analyzed","index_analyzer":"keyword","search_analyzer":"whitespace","type":"string"},"lang":{"index":"analyzed","index_analyzer":"keyword","search_analyzer":"whitespace","type":"string"},"id":{"type":"double"},"allTags":{"type":"multi_field","fields":{"allTags":{"index":"analyzed","index_analyzer":"keyword","search_analyzer":"whitespace","type":"string"},"words":{"type":"string","index":"analyzed","index_analyzer":"index_words","search_analyzer":"search_words"},"grams":{"type":"string","index":"analyzed","index_analyzer":"index_grams","search_analyzer":"search_grams"}}},"debtCharOverloaded":{"type":"boolean"},"ruleKey":{"index":"analyzed","index_analyzer":"keyword","search_analyzer":"whitespace","type":"string"},"createdAt":{"type":"date","format":"date_time"},"repo":{"index":"analyzed","index_analyzer":"keyword","search_analyzer":"whitespace","type":"string"},"name":{"type":"multi_field","fields":{"sort":{"type":"string","index":"analyzed","analyzer":"sortable"},"words":{"type":"string","index":"analyzed","index_analyzer":"index_words","search_analyzer":"search_words"},"name":{"index":"analyzed","index_analyzer":"keyword","search_analyzer":"whitespace","type":"string"},"grams":{"type":"string","index":"analyzed","index_analyzer":"index_grams","search_analyzer":"search_grams"}}},"debtChar":{"index":"analyzed","index_analyzer":"keyword","search_analyzer":"whitespace","type":"string"},"htmlDesc":{"type":"multi_field","fields":{"words":{"type":"string","index":"analyzed","index_analyzer":"index_words","search_analyzer":"search_words"},"htmlDesc":{"index":"analyzed","index_analyzer":"keyword","search_analyzer":"whitespace","type":"string"}}},"effortToFix":{"index":"analyzed","index_analyzer":"keyword","search_analyzer":"whitespace","type":"string"},"_debtRemFnOffset":{"index":"analyzed","index_analyzer":"keyword","search_analyzer":"whitespace","type":"string"},"debtRemFnType":{"index":"analyzed","index_analyzer":"keyword","search_analyzer":"whitespace","type":"string"},"key":{"type":"multi_field","fields":{"sort":{"type":"string","index":"analyzed","analyzer":"sortable"},"key":{"index":"analyzed","index_analyzer":"keyword","search_analyzer":"whitespace","type":"string"}}},"tags":{"index":"analyzed","index_analyzer":"keyword","search_analyzer":"whitespace","type":"string"},"templateKey":{"index":"analyzed","index_analyzer":"keyword","search_analyzer":"whitespace","type":"string"},"internalKey":{"index":"analyzed","index_analyzer":"keyword","search_analyzer":"whitespace","type":"string"},"debtSubCharOverloaded":{"type":"boolean"},"status":{"index":"analyzed","index_analyzer":"keyword","search_analyzer":"whitespace","type":"string"},"noteUpdatedAt":{"type":"date","format":"date_time"},"debtSubChar":{"index":"analyzed","index_analyzer":"keyword","search_analyzer":"whitespace","type":"string"},"mdDesc":{"index":"analyzed","index_analyzer":"keyword","search_analyzer":"whitespace","type":"string"},"noteCreatedAt":{"type":"date","format":"date_time"},"severity":{"index":"analyzed","index_analyzer":"keyword","search_analyzer":"whitespace","type":"string"},"params":{"dynamic":"true","properties":{"description":{"type":"multi_field","fields":{"words":{"type":"string","index":"analyzed","index_analyzer":"index_words","search_analyzer":"search_words"},"description":{"index":"analyzed","index_analyzer":"keyword","search_analyzer":"whitespace","type":"string"}}},"name":{"index":"analyzed","index_analyzer":"keyword","search_analyzer":"whitespace","type":"string"},"defaultValue":{"index":"analyzed","index_analyzer":"keyword","search_analyzer":"whitespace","type":"string"},"type":{"index":"analyzed","index_analyzer":"keyword","search_analyzer":"whitespace","type":"string"}},"type":"nested"},"sysTags":{"index":"analyzed","index_analyzer":"keyword","search_analyzer":"whitespace","type":"string"},"_debtRemFnCoefficient":{"index":"analyzed","index_analyzer":"keyword","search_analyzer":"whitespace","type":"string"},"_debtSubChar":{"index":"analyzed","index_analyzer":"keyword","search_analyzer":"whitespace","type":"string"},"updatedAt":{"type":"date","format":"date_time"},"_debtRemFnType":{"index":"analyzed","index_analyzer":"keyword","search_analyzer":"whitespace","type":"string"},"isTemplate":{"type":"boolean"},"markdownNote":{"index":"analyzed","index_analyzer":"keyword","search_analyzer":"whitespace","type":"string"},"debtRemFnCoefficient":{"index":"analyzed","index_analyzer":"keyword","search_analyzer":"whitespace","type":"string"}},"_all":{"enabled":false}}'
at org.sonar.server.es.request.ProxyPutMappingRequestBuilder.get(ProxyPutMappingRequestBuilder.java:43) ~[sonar-server-5.4.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.es.request.ProxyPutMappingRequestBuilder.get(ProxyPutMappingRequestBuilder.java:31) ~[sonar-server-5.4.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.search.BaseIndex.initializeIndex(BaseIndex.java:176) ~[sonar-server-5.4.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.search.BaseIndex.start(BaseIndex.java:116) ~[sonar-server-5.4.jar:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_99]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_99]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_99]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_99]
at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110) ~[picoc
```

There's obviously a problem here with the embedded elasticsearch but I haven't been able to figure out it out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how elastic got corrupted, but wiping the contents of /var/local/sonar/data and restoring mysql fixed it.